# Android : how to get value from assets and pass it thru array

Tags: android, arrays

[image: Problem image file]
I want to short my code length by using array.If I have 100 button or image view I have to write for 100 . I want to get value from assets folder and pass it in to array . how to use

```
String[] colorNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorList);
String[] animalNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animalList);
```

**Current working code :**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String key = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Button btn1,btn2;
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    if(key.equals("animalIntent") )
{
    btn1.setText("cat");
    btn2.setText("dog");
```

// same for 100 button ............. here i want to short my code

```
} else {
    btn1.setText("red");
    btn2.setText("blue");
}
}

public void btn1(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String key = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
    if(key.equals("animalIntent") )
    {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat);
```

// same for 100 image view ............. here i want to short my code

```
    } else {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
    }
}

public void btn2(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String key = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
    if(key.equals("animalIntent") )
    {
      image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dog);


    } else {
      image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
    }
}
```

[image: result with working code]

Comment: did you added 100 buttons through xml?

Comment: currently i am working with 8 buttons. so I can check with 8 buttons

Comment: keep reference of buttons in `List<Button>`

Comment: Please guide me through code. I m new to android .

Comment: do u want the buttons in two column??

Comment: yes. I want in two coloumn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you should use GridView,it would be best option. try the below sample code.
Step-1 add the gridview in your drag.xml

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
```

Step-2 Declare the variables and get the grid view reference.

```
GridView gridview;
     Integer[] drawableIds = { R.drawable.poster1, R.drawable.poster2, R.drawable.poster3, R.drawable.poster4,
            R.drawable.poster5 };
    String[] colorNames = { "poster one", "poster two", "poster three", "poster four", "poster five" };
```

//In OnCreate() method add

```
gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(this, drawableIds, colorNames));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Step-3 create a class for grid adapter CustomGridAdapter.class

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Integer[] drawableitems;
    private String[] drawablelabel;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, Integer[] drawableitems, String[] drawablelabel) {

        this.context = context;
        this.drawablelabel = drawablelabel;
        this.drawableitems = drawableitems;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return drawableitems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(drawablelabel[position]);
        holder.imageItem.setImageResource(drawableitems[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;

    }
}
```

Add custom view for grid grid_item.xml in layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: wow ...I am looking for this process. Code is working perfectly . Thanks a lot.

Comment: how to convert with question answer and check the correct answer using this method.

Comment: in this code you are useing "drawable" But I want to use from "Assests" Folder

Comment: don't put the drawable in the assests put them in drawable folder.It is not wise to put there.

Comment: Thanks I'll use drawable folder . Could you please convert this code as a quiz. it will be gr8 help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try yourself.Stack Overflow is not for your job to be done.It is for help & queries.If you want it to be done better hire someone.

Comment: ya sure . thanks for your help. I'll try with myself. It's time to learn :)